# How do you determine if a Shopify App has an existing backend role, and how do you modify it?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

My team and I have created a Shopify App using their CLI and framework. We are attempting to spin it up locally and we follow the terminal prompts the following steps:

`Before proceeding, your project needs to be associated with an app.`

`?  Create this project as a new app on Shopify?`

`✔  No, connect it to an existing app`

`?  Which existing app is this for?`

`✔  App Name`

`?  Which store would you like to use to view your project?`

`✔  Store Name`

Following `Store Name` we receive this error:

`You can only have one web with the backend role in your app`

We have tried using a different app, and a different store, but still yield the same result.

Answer (score 0):

The CLI examines TOML files. If you set one TOML file for your App in general, you then set one for the front-end and one for the back-end. If you have two set to back-end, the CLI will puke.

Check your TOML files.